Chainlink automation custom logic not triggering but working manually
I've got a problem and i can't understand it.
I have a custom logic automation on polygon blockchain.
I have two triggers.
The first one works flawlessly,
But the second don't want to work.
And doing the same manually works just fine.
I had an earlier version of my smart contract that was working just fine.
Can anyone help me figure out why its not trigering ?
// The automaton guiding our celestial course - Chainlink Upkeep

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) public view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        // Decisions abound at the helm of our cosmic journey. When our spaceship registers a full complement of intrepid Cosmoonauts, it initiates a wide scan of the cosmos, sending out a request for celestial coordinates of resource-rich planets. Upon receipt of this crucial data, our navigation system leaps into action, divvying up the discovered celestial bodies among the Cosmoonauts who have yet to stake their claim on a new world.
        upkeepNeeded = randomNumberGenerated || allParticipantsRegistered;

        // We don't require any specific maintenance data in our cosmic journey.
        // Therefore, we return our received checkData as performData.
        performData = checkData;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) public override {
        // We ensure our celestial course still requires an adjustment.
        require(randomNumberGenerated || allParticipantsRegistered, "No upkeep needed");
        
        //Have the celestial coordinates of resource-rich planets reached us? Ignite the hyperdrives! It's time to launch the exploration mission and distribute the interstellar spoils among the fortunate Cosmoonauts

       //This one is not triggering
        if (randomNumberGenerated) {
            randomNumberGenerated = false;
            runGame(); 
        }
        
        // Is our spaceship teeming with brave Cosmoonauts? Power up the star mapping sequence! We are now setting course to chart the undiscovered galaxies and their bountiful planets.
        //This one works perfectly launching the vrf and receiving the numbers
        if (allParticipantsRegistered) {
            allParticipantsRegistered = false;
            drawnumbers();
        }

        
    }


    // Manual function to test runGame
    function manualRunGame() external onlyFGCreator {
        require(randomNumberGenerated, "Random number not generated yet");
        randomNumberGenerated = false;
        runGame();//This one runs smoothly while launched manually
    }

    // Manual function to test drawNumbers
    function manualDrawNumbers() external onlyFGCreator {
        require(allParticipantsRegistered, "Not all participants registered yet");
        allParticipantsRegistered = false;
        drawnumbers();
    }

The upkeep Id is 37786756493441211265373049430028170682412354847343002706062893578728763693235
I can't figure out how to get the error log or any information on why it isn't working...
I tryed manually and it runs smoothly, so i don't know what i can do.
I also set the gas limit of the upkeep at 2 500 000 even if it uses just a few cents...
As asked by Syed here is the code that change the
Trigger value :
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] calldata motsAleatoires)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(!requetesTraitees[requestId], "La requete a deja ete traitee.");

        // Each number in the array is a fresh, new coordinate for our Cosmoonauts!
        for (uint i = 0; i < motsAleatoires.length; i++) {
            
            listeNombresAleatoires.push(motsAleatoires[i]);

        }
        // We've processed this batch, so let's not repeat it.
        requetesTraitees[requestId] = true;
        requetesRestantes--;

        // When all the requests have been processed and we've got all our random numbers, we're ready to roll.
        if (requetesRestantes == 0) {
            // An event to signal our ground control (aka the front end) that all the coordinates for the mission have been generated.
            emit TousLesNombresAleatoiresGeneres();
            randomNumberGenerated = true; // The random number generation is finished. The stars are now aligned for the launch!
        }
    }


Can you add the portion of code where you're making randomNumberGenerated as true ?

How could it be releavant ?
I checked the value and it's true as intended. That's why its working manually with the code i put under.
Everything should run smoothly with automation if it runs manually am i wrong ?
Ill add it under because it's too long for a comment.

Does your runGame function have a modifier ?

Yes, it is internal and subfunctions of it also.

I mean modifer like onlyOwner or so, not the visibility.

No, it's the only rules of the functions. No Onlyowner or anything like that.

The way you're using onlyFGCreator in manualRunGame(). Are you also using the same in runGame() ?

Not at all, i used this modifier on the manual function so no one can do it, only us. But the functions being internal and handled by the upkeep i didn't need it.

Okay. It's weird then. As you've mentioned, drawnumbers() is getting executed successfully by the upkeep making the allParticipantsRegistered as false and requesting random words and making the randomNumberGenerated as true. But what it's unable to do, is to trigger the upkeep again and  execute the runGame().

Can you share your codebase via gist, so that I can try debugging the same on my end?

Can you elaborate what exactly do you mean by "handles less tokens"?

Are you doing any transaction depending on those prize values ?

Ohhh i think i found why. I raised the gas to 5 000 000 and added some link and it look like it worked !!

Ok i added 1 Link and 5 000 000 gas limit and it worked XD
